# How to export iCloud photos with proper datetime

Tags: ios, icloud, photos.app

I'm using Photos app on macOS to export iCloud photos, because it's easiest possible way.

The app itself is showing date and time of every photo in the header, but when Exporting the Originals everything is saved with wrong Date Modified/Created date. EXIF date is correct but f.e. pictures from internet don't have any metadata. Same applies to videos (no EXIF).

- I tried AirDrop from iOS to macOS also, but same behaviour.
- checked extended attributes (`xattr` and `mdls`) for correct date, but no luck..
- checked datetime of local files in LocalMacbook.photoslibrary after setting `Download Originals to this Mac.` in Photos -> Preferences

[image: Photos app screenshot with date and time]

The best I could get was Export all into subfolders named by "Moment Name". So I have at least date:

[image]

---

Is it possible to export photos/videos with correct date & time via Apple software? iOS/macOS Photos app is clearly able to display the correct date and time.

`Photos version 4.0 (3461.7.160) on Mojave`

Comment: I have the same issue. Noticed the file modified/created timestamps I get on exported files are likely to match those of when that file was created on a the device I was exporting from. So if it's an iPad with "*optimise storage*" on that needs to download the file first, then it will be the current timestamp. Conversely, if this is an iPhone and it's the file that was there since I shot it, then it would have the original timestamp. I went to https://www.apple.com/feedback/photos/ and submitted a feedback suggesting the Photos app updates the created/modified timestamp when exporting.

Comment: Thanks for the Moment Name tip by the way, at least something.